# Golbach's partitions: is there always one common prime in $G(n)$ and $G(n+6)$ , $n \ge 8$ (or a counterexample)?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I am trying to find a counterexample for the following expression when $d=6$. ($G(n)$ = Goldbach partition of the even number $n$)

${\forall}$ n=2*k / k${\in}$N, n${\geq}$8

${\exists}$(${p_i}$,${p_j}$) /
(${p_i}$,${p_j}$) ${\in}$ G(n), 
(${p_i}$,${p_j}$+d) ${\in}$ G(n+d)

for a fixed distance $d=2*q\ /\ q$${\in}\Bbb N$, $d\geq 2$

It means that the Goldbach partitions of the even number n, and the even number n+d, at least contain one common prime ${p_i}$, being the counterpart primes ${p_j}$ and ${p_j}$+d, and d is a fixed even distance, for instance always $2$, always $4$, always $6$, etc. so:

${p_i}$+${p_j}$$=n$
and
${p_i}$+(${p_j}$+d)$=n+d$

I have found very quickly counterexamples when the distance $d$ is set to $2$,$4$ or $8$:

$d=2 n=38 n+2=40$ do not have any common primes in $G(38),G(40)$

$d=4 n=172 n+4=176$ do not have any common primes in $G(172),G(176)$

$d=8 n=38 n+8=46$ do not have any common primes in $G(38),G(46)$

But in the case $d=6$, I have run a test for the first $9000$ even numbers (after that point my computer slows down very much) and I did not find a counterexample (assuming the code is correct), so in the case of n and n+6, I have found always at least one common prime in $G(n)$ and $G(n+6)$, and the counterparts are a couple of sexy primes at least for any even number $n$ between $[8,9000]$. So another way of saying this is that there is always a couple of sexy prime shared between $G(n)$ and $G(n+6)$ when the even number $n$ is greater or equal to $8$.

I am very curious because for $d=2,4,8$ was very easy to find a quick counterexample, but not in the case of d=6 probably because is greater than the $9000^{th}$ even number or a test error (I am assuming I did correctly my test, but it could happen).

**UPDATE 2015/04/09**

Note: all the explanation above was assuming that:

$\ \ n=p+q\ /\ p\le q$ and

$\ \ n+6 = p+(q+6)$,

> But there is also the possibility that the common prime $p\gt q$ **(*)**.
>   In that case, the sexy primes are $q$ in the list of primes of $G(n)$
>   and **$q-6$** in the list of primes of $G(n+6)$.

Below there is an extension of the explanation (for the cases in which $p\le q$, but same idea would apply for **(*)** $p\gt q$):

For any $n≥8$ even seems to exists at least a prime pair $(p,q)\ /\ n=p+q$, in which $p$ or $q$ has a sexy prime counterpart, e.g $q+6$, also prime, and $n+6=p+(q+6)$.

> E.g. $n=8=3+5$ and $n+6=14=3+11$, where the 'shared' or 'fixed' prime
>   in $n=8$ and $n=14$ is $3$ and the sexy primes are $5$ in $n=8$ and
>   $11(=5+6)$ in $n=14$.
>
> E.g.: $n=10=3+7$ and $n+6=16=3+13$, so the 'shared' prime is $3$ in
>   $n=10$ and $n=16$ and the sexy primes are $7$ in $n=10$ and $13$ in
>   $n=16$.
>
> E.g.: $n=17890=17837+53$ and $n+6=17896=17837+59$, in the same way
>   than above.

I still did not find counterexamples, every Goldbach partition of a given even number $n$ and $n+6$ seems to cover this property.

E.g. this is a picture of a visualization of the list of Goldbach primes for each $n \in [466..480]$:

[image: Goldbach primes in 466..480 and the sexy primes counterparts in n and n+6]

Each column is the list of Goldbach primes for the even number $n$ written at the top, and the primes below (top-down) are in ascending order the primes $p$ able to sum up $n=p+q$, where $q$ is also prime.

In the picture there are samples of the common prime behavior, in different colors, for the following even numbers $(n,n+6)$:

$(n=466$,$n=472)$

$(n=468$,$n=474)$

$(n=470$,$n=476)$

$(n=472$,$n=478)$

$(n=474$,$n=480)$

E.g.
$n=466=5+461$ and $n=466+6=472=5+(461+6)=5+467$, so (a) in this example $p=5$ is in the list of Goldbach primes of $n=466$ and $n+6=472$, and (b) the sexy prime $q=461$ belongs to the list of $n=466$, and its counterpart sexy prime $q+6=467$ belongs to the list of Goldbach primes of $n=472$.

But it seems it does not matter which random even $n\ge8$ is taken, always the list of Goldbach primes for the even number $n$ shares a prime $p$ with the list of $n+6$ and there is a couple of sexy primes $(q,q+6)$ (if $p \le q$) or $(q,q-6)$ (if $p \gt q$) shared between $n$ and $n+6$, $q$ belongs to the list of $n$ and $q+6$ (if $p \le q$) or $q-6$ (if $p \gt q$) belongs to the list of $n+6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are asking if, for each even $n\ge8,$ there is a prime $p$ such that $n-p$ and $n-p+6$ are both prime. I verified that this is true for all $n\le10^8$ by finding appropriate $p$. Heuristically $n$ fails with probability
$$\begin{align}
&\prod_{3\le p\le n-3}1-\frac{1}{\log(n-p)} \cdot \frac{1}{\log(n-p+6)}\\
\approx&\prod_{3\le p\le n-3}1-\frac{1}{\log^2n}\\
=&\ \exp\sum_{3\le p\le n-3}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{\log^2n}\right)\\
\approx&\ \exp-\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{3\le p\le n-3}\frac{1}{\log^2n}\\
=&\ \exp\frac{1-\pi(n)}{\log^2n}\\
\approx&\ \exp\frac{-n}{\log^3n}
\end{align}$$
and so the 'probability' that it fails for $n>10^8$ is bounded above by
$$
\int_{10^8}^{+\infty} \exp\frac{-x}{\log^3x} \text d x<10^{-6944}.
$$

Comment: what you did is simple awesome, thank you! your understanding was correct but due to my bad explanation it does not include the second case.  The first case is the one you did, in which $p \le (n-p)$, for that case $n-p$ and $n-p+6$ are primes. The other case is when $p \gt (n-p)$, for that case $n-p$ and $n-p-6$ are primes. If you add that case, the probabilities to fail might be even smaller. May I share two more thoughts? 1) why only d=6 seems to be good? for d=8,2,4 I quickly find a counterexample. 2) Is it equivalent to the Goldbach conjecture, or another way of expressing it?

Comment: I meant "simply awesome" not "simple awesome" (cannot reedit)

Comment: It's stronger than Goldbach -- conceivably this cold fail even if Goldbach is true.Practically speaking both are extremely likely. $d=6$ is not very special -- it's a bit more likely to work since it's divisible by 2 and 3 (30 would be better, adding in also 5) but that's not a big deal. It might easily have had a small counterexample but it happens not to have -- 8,2,4 probably don't have any large counterexamples.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I always learn from you!

Comment: hi! sorry to bother you, regarding Goldbach's conjecture, if some day you have time and you are interested in the topic, please I would appreciate very much to know your opinion about a new question about the same topic I wrote recently. I always learn from you very much and the content might be a new point of view about the conjecture. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287585/conjecture-the-set-of-maximum-order-elements-to-mod-n-contains-one-pair-of-gold

Comment: @iadvd: I can't understand the question you ask there, sorry.

Comment: thanks for checking it, I know it is difficult to catch, trying to explain it was a pain!! :)